# Automatically proceed to a webpage if user enters 2000 in a form

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I would like a user to enter the number 2000 in a form and as soon as they enter the last 0 to take them to the next webpage. I don't want them to have to press enter or a button.

I am thinking something like this but I can't work out what to do:

```
<form id="form" action="#" method="post" name="result" style="align:center;">
<td>
     <input type="text" name="id" id="input_field" maxlength="10">
</td>
</form>

<script>
$("#input_field").keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val().length == 4)
        $('#form :submit').click();
})
```

​

I have tried the approach below but it still doesn't automatically submit:

```
<form id="form" action="#" method="post" name="result" style="align:center;">
 <input type="text" name="id" id="input_field" maxlength="4">
</form>

<script>
$("#input_field").keyup(function(){
 if($(this).val().length == 4 && $(this).val() == "2000") {
     $('#form')
           .attr({action: "stackoverflow.com"})
           .submit();
 }
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of `$('#form :submit').click();` use `$('#form').submit()`

Comment: If you check for length == 4 you trigger the submit with any four diggit entry. You could simply check val == 2000 to limit it to only one specific number. Btw, submitting forms without the user actually hitting a submit or enter is 'unexpected behaviour' jfyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
 $("#input_field").keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val().length == 4 && $(this).val() == "2000") {
         $('#form')
               .attr({action: "YOUR-DESTINATION.php"})
               .submit();
     }
 });
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/o3uyk190/

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work I have edited the original post to show what i have done

Comment: Note than I add `.attr() ` function. You can remove if you don't need it

Comment: It works since the first time xD I don't know how are you making for don't work. Greetings

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#input_field").keyup(function(){

     field_value = $(this).val();

     // There's no point checking for length. If you want
     // to submit when they enter 2000 make that your IF
     if(field_value == 2000) {
         $('#form').submit();
     }

});
```